# How to write Navision CALCDATE function in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, navision, dynamics-nav

Here is a definition of Navision [CALCDATE function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/calcdate-function--date-):

```
NewDate := CALCDATE(DateExpression [, Date])
```

It takes two parameters:

- DateExpression which in Navision has type [DateFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/dateformula-data-type) which in SQL is stored as varchar(32)
- Date, which in SQL means DateTime. To simplify the problem I'm assuming it's not optional (in Navsion, it is)

I need to access Navision data from SQL and do some calculations based on DateFormulas stored there.
I know how to write such function in SQL CLR, so please don't include this in your answer.

1. How to write CALCDATE function in TSQL?
2. [Optional] Is it possible to do it in SQL query only, using some (auxiliary) CTEs (this will allow me to not add function to Navsion database, therefore not modify it)?
3. Does SQL CLR is my only option?

Main problem I have with this function is that it seems that it must be done in following steps:

1. Parse DateExpression
2. Apply parsing result to Date parameter and produce new date.

But how to do the parsing part?
For example DateExpression = '-CW+1W+1D' means that we must do 3 things with our Date parameter in exactly this order:

1. Find last Monday (current week start) '-CW'
2. Add 1 week (7 days) '+1W'
3. Add 1 day '+1D'

It can be written in shorter form '+CW+1D', which means next monday and 1 day.
Generally this varchar(32) can contain 1 or more such expressions and they must be applied in provided order on Date parameter.

How to parse such varchar(32) in SQL?
In C# I would do it in a loop or recursively, but how to do it in SQL (sets)?
How to convert such structured varchar(32) into set of formulas.
Maybe I need to convert it somehow to XML and query it using SQL Server XML functions - but how?

---

EDIT:
How I want to use it?

I want to use this function as part of larger query.
For example (simplified):

```sql
    select ... 
    from [Issued Reminder Header] as reminder
    join [Reminder Terms] as terms on ...
    join [Reminder Level] as level on ...
    cross apply dbo.CalcDate(level.[Grace Period], reminder.[Posting Date]) as calculated
```

What I mean, is that level.[Grace Period] is in table that can be edited by users and can change any moment. So I cannot take any shortcuts and precalculate few values.

Comment: Writing expression parser in T-SQL would be pretty difficult. If you manage to do it its performance would be horrible. Unless you have a small fixed set of tokens that you can search and replace with certain function calls, like replace `+1W` with `DATEADD(day, 7, <>)`.

Comment: Pick any solution that isn't pure T-SQL and it'll be better in the long run -- whether it's client-side C#, CLR functions in another database or making Navision do the work and importing the data from there (using something like PowerBI, for example). If you absolutely have to use T-SQL, try to make it as simple as possible -- see how many unique formulas you really need to support with `DISTINCT`; if it's not too many you could just hard-code it.

Comment: What is the use-case? Will the _DateExpression_ need to be parsed every time or is it (relatively) static such that you could create an equivalent TSQL expression and cache it for execution? That might give you the freedom to use a more suitable tool for parsing and creating a replacement expression.

Comment: Your edit does not answer my question. Is `level.[Grace Period]` a column that has five distinct values that are never changed after they are assigned or thousands of distinct values that are updated every few minutes? In the first case you could implement a function that handles five specific cases without any parsing, while the second case is likely better addressed with a more flexible (and painful) solution.

Comment: @HABO  The time you have taken to type out both your comments was enough to click the link in the first line of the question and see what is possible in the expression they are looking to parse.

Comment: @iamdave That's where I started. Just because something is possible doesn't mean someone needs it, or that it makes sense. (`'-65535Y42WD-CW'` is syntactically valid, but what are the semantics?) My comments have been addressed in a subsequent edit to the question by the OP: "[Grace Period] is in table that can be edited by users and can change any moment. So I cannot take any shortcuts and precalculate few values."

Answer (score 1):

This answer is here primarily as an example in how silly this would be to try and implement in pure SQL (and also because I considered it an interesting challenge).

It is not intended to be used in any kind of production capacity and I am not even sure it properly implements the functionality of `calcdate` or would work across all the possible scenarios that `calcdate` allows.

#### SQL

```
declare @d date = '19960521';

declare @t table(Expression varchar(32),ExpectedValue date);
insert into @t values
 ('-CW+1W+1D','19960528')
,('CQ+1M-10D','19960720')
,('+CW+1D','19960528')
,('+CW+1WD','19960528')
,('CM+30D','19960630')
,('-WD2','19960514')
,('WD3','19960522')
,('-D3','19960503')
,('-D27','19960427')
,('D3','19960603')
,('D27','19960527')
,('10D','19960531')
,('1W','19960528')
,('W2','19970106')
,('-W2','19960108')
,('M12','19961201')
,('M2','19970201')
,('-M2','19960201')
,('Q4','19961001')
,('Q2','19970401')
,('-Q2','19960401')
;


with v as
(
    select Expression
          ,ExpectedValue
          ,stuff(replace(replace(case when left(Expression,1) not in('+','-') then '+' else '' end + Expression
                                ,'+','|+'
                                )
                        ,'-','|-'
                        )
                ,1,1,''
                ) + '|||' as Fmt
    from @t
)
,p as
(
    select Expression
            ,ExpectedValue
            ,Fmt
            ,left(v.Fmt,charindex('|',v.Fmt,0)-1) as p1
            ,substring(v.Fmt
                      ,charindex('|',v.Fmt,0)+1
                      ,(charindex('|',v.Fmt,charindex('|',v.Fmt,0)+1)-1) - (charindex('|',v.Fmt,0))
                      ) as p2
            ,replace(substring(v.Fmt
                              ,charindex('|',v.Fmt,charindex('|',v.Fmt,0)+1)+1
                              ,999
                              )
                    ,'|'
                    ,''
                    ) as p3
    from v
)

    select @d as GivenDate
          ,p.Expression
          ,p.ExpectedValue
          ,cast(v3.retp3 as date) as ReturnedValue
          ,case when p.ExpectedValue = v3.retp3 then 'Match' else 'No Match' end as ValueCheck
    from p
        outer apply(values(case when substring(p1,2,1) = 'C'                -- <Prefix><Unit>
                                then case substring(p1,3,2)
                                       when 'D' then @d
                                       when 'WD' then @d
                                       when 'W' then dateadd(week, datediff(week,0,@d) + case when left(p1,1) = '+' then 1 else 0 end, 0)
                                       when 'M' then case when left(p1,1) = '+' then eomonth(@d) else dateadd(day,1,eomonth(@d,-1)) end
                                       when 'Q' then dateadd(day,case when left(p1,1) = '+' then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter,0,@d) + case when left(p1,1) = '+' then 1 else 0 end, 0))
                                       when 'Y' then dateadd(year, datediff(year,0,@d) + case when left(p1,1) = '+' then 1 else 0 end, 0)
                                     else ''
                                     end
                            when isnumeric(substring(p1,2,1)) = 1       -- <Number><Unit>
                                then case when right(p1,2) = 'WD'
                                          then dateadd(day,cast(replace(p1,'WD','') as int),@d)
                                          else case right(p1,1)
                                                 when 'D' then dateadd(day,cast(replace(p1,'D','') as int),@d)
                                                 when 'W' then dateadd(week,cast(replace(p1,'W','') as int),@d)
                                                 when 'M' then dateadd(month,cast(replace(p1,'M','') as int),@d)
                                                 when 'Q' then dateadd(quarter,cast(replace(p1,'Q','') as int),@d)
                                                 when 'Y' then dateadd(year,cast(replace(p1,'Y','') as int),@d)
                                                 end
                                          end
                            when isnumeric(substring(p1,2,1)) = 0       -- <Unit><Number>
                                then case when substring(p1,2,2) = 'WD'
                                          then dateadd(day,right(p1,1)-1,dateadd(week, datediff(week,0,@d) - case when left(p1,1) = '-' then 1 else 0 end, 0))
                                          else case substring(p1,2,1)
                                                 when 'D' then dateadd(day,abs(cast(replace(p1,'D','') as int))-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@d) + case when abs(cast(replace(p1,'D','') as int)) < day(@d) then 1 else 0 end + case when sign(cast(replace(p1,'D','') as int)) = -1 then -1 else 0 end, 0))
                                                 when 'W' then dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,dateadd(week,abs(cast(replace(p1,'W','') as int))-1,datefromparts(year(@d) + case when abs(cast(replace(p1,'W','') as int)) <= datepart(week,@d) then 1 else 0 end + case when sign(cast(replace(p1,'W','') as int)) = -1 then -1 else 0 end,1,1))), 0)
                                                 when 'M' then datefromparts(year(@d) + case when abs(cast(replace(p1,'M','') as int)) <= month(@d) then 1 else 0 end + case when sign(cast(replace(p1,'M','') as int)) = -1 then -1 else 0 end,abs(cast(replace(p1,'M','') as int)),1)
                                                 when 'Q' then datefromparts(year(@d) + case when abs(cast(replace(p1,'Q','') as int)) <= datepart(quarter,@d) then 1 else 0 end + case when sign(cast(replace(p1,'Q','') as int)) = -1 then -1 else 0 end,((abs(cast(replace(p1,'Q','') as int))-1)*3)+1,1)
                                                 when 'Y' then datefromparts(abs(cast(replace(p1,'Y','') as int)),1,1)
                                                 end
                                          end
                            else ''
                            end
                          )
                   ) as v1(retp1)
        outer apply(values(case right(p2,1)
                           when 'D' then dateadd(day,cast(replace(replace(p2,'W',''),'D','') as int),retp1)
                           when 'W' then dateadd(day,cast(replace(p2,'W','') as int) * 7,retp1)
                           when 'M' then dateadd(month,cast(replace(p2,'M','') as int),retp1)
                           when 'Q' then dateadd(quarter,cast(replace(p2,'Q','') as int),retp1)
                           when 'Y' then dateadd(year,cast(replace(p2,'Y','') as int),retp1)
                           else retp1
                           end
                          )
                   ) as v2(retp2)
        outer apply(values(case right(p3,1)
                            when 'D' then dateadd(day,cast(replace(replace(p3,'W',''),'D','') as int),retp2)
                            when 'W' then dateadd(day,cast(replace(p3,'W','') as int) * 7,retp2)
                            when 'M' then dateadd(month,cast(replace(p3,'M','') as int),retp2)
                            when 'Q' then dateadd(quarter,cast(replace(p3,'Q','') as int),retp2)
                            when 'Y' then dateadd(year,cast(replace(p3,'Y','') as int),retp2)
                            else retp2
                            end
                          )
                   ) as v3(retp3);
```

#### Output

| GivenDate | Expression | ExpectedValue | ReturnedValue | ValueCheck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1996-05-21 | -CW+1W+1D | 1996-05-28 | 1996-05-28 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | CQ+1M-10D | 1996-07-20 | 1996-07-20 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | +CW+1D | 1996-05-28 | 1996-05-28 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | +CW+1WD | 1996-05-28 | 1996-05-28 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | CM+30D | 1996-06-30 | 1996-06-30 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -WD2 | 1996-05-14 | 1996-05-14 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | WD3 | 1996-05-22 | 1996-05-22 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -D3 | 1996-05-03 | 1996-05-03 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -D27 | 1996-04-27 | 1996-04-27 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | D3 | 1996-06-03 | 1996-06-03 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | D27 | 1996-05-27 | 1996-05-27 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | 10D | 1996-05-31 | 1996-05-31 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | 1W | 1996-05-28 | 1996-05-28 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | W2 | 1997-01-06 | 1997-01-06 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -W2 | 1996-01-08 | 1996-01-08 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | M12 | 1996-12-01 | 1996-12-01 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | M2 | 1997-02-01 | 1997-02-01 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -M2 | 1996-02-01 | 1996-02-01 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | Q4 | 1996-10-01 | 1996-10-01 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | Q2 | 1997-04-01 | 1997-04-01 | Match |
| 1996-05-21 | -Q2 | 1996-04-01 | 1996-04-01 | Match |